# Goodness of fit test for time varying copulas

Tags: programming

I am looking for Matlab or R codes for goodness of fit test of time varying copulas. I am able to calculate AIC for them using the Patton copula toolbox, but i want to do goodness of fit test using the known tests such as Cramer-von Mises , Anderson-Darling and etc.

any help would be appreciated.

Regards 
Esmaeel